# how to set page from a link by value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a link to another page based on the value inside database column. 
table member

```
user_id     name    point
--------------------------
 1          sid     90
 2          mike    100 
 3          john    110
```

for example, if we click this link `<a href="chkpoint.php?user_id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" >Buy</a>` it will check value in point column, if the value  are below or equal than 100 it will go to page `buy1.php` else it will go to `topup.php`. so base on table above, for sid click Buy link, he will go to `topup.php` and for mike and john click Buy link they will go to `buy1.php`. so how can i create `chkpoint.php`? so far this is my code for `chkpoint.php`

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx; dbname=xxx', 'xxx', '') or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['user_id']) && !empty($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM member WHERE user_id =:user_id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    extract($row);
} else {
    header("Location: memrec.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['point']) <= "100") {
    header("Location: topup.php");
} else {
    header("Location: buy1.php");
}
?>
```

but that code above doesn't working.

Comment: `isset($_GET['point'])<="100"` is wrong. `isset()` returns a boolean. You need to first check if it exist and then check the value: `isset($_GET['point']) && $_GET['point'] <= 100`

Comment: You can also remove the `isset()`-part from `isset($_GET['user_id']) && !empty($_GET['user_id'])` since empty() does the same as isset() + some more checks.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Be careful: `!empty()` and `isset()` are not the same. If `$_GET['user_id']=0`, `!empty()` will return FALSE, but `isset()` will return TRUE

Comment: @BeetleJuice That's why I wrote _"+ some more checks"_

Comment: *"but that code above doesn't working"* - You're going to have to explain that and how `$row['user_id']` is being populated from.

Comment: `or die(mysql_error())` that doesn't work with PDO, so that may very well be *why* your code failed. Btw; are you not seeing these comments?

Comment: if you're just going to respond to "answers", then stick with them, I've moved on now. Good luck. Edit: oh and this `if (isset($_GET['point']) <= "100")` is invalid syntax, as a last word.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorru, i don't notice your comment. `$row['user_id']` come form previous page tht need to check value in column point either 100 or more 100.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(isset($_GET['point'])<="100")
```

With

```
if ( (int)$point < 100 )
```

Comment: You might want to add how the OP should set `$point` first. Just changing the above will throw an "Undefined variable $point"-warning.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the OP uses `extract($row)` which will populate the local variable table with variables named after the keys of the `$row` array.  Since the DB data was fetched with `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and the DB table has a `point` column, there is no need to set `$point`

Comment: Ah. My bad... You're correct. The OP confused me by using `$_GET['point']`, which got me thinking that the variable comes from the URL instead of the DB. :-)

Comment: @BeetleJuice sir are you sure just change `if(isset($_GET['point'])<="100")` to `if ( (int)$point < 100 )`?

Comment: @aini I can't be sure because I don't have the application and DB here to test, but you can check

Comment: @BeetleJuice sir. i've try in xampp but its bring me to `locahost/dashboard` instead of `buy1.php` or `topup.php`

Comment: @aini what if you use the full path in the header (start with forward slash) ?  `Location: /path/to/buy1.php`

Comment: @BeetleJuice same thing happen sir. its bring me to `localhost/dashboard`